# Delete the nth line from a matched string (which only occurs once in the file)

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have a question related to deletion of strings that appear at the `n+2` position after the matched string which is at position `n` using `awk` for multiple files. I am able to print it using the command:

```
 awk -F '/radius-server/{nr[NR+4]}; NR in nr' *
```

Where the matched string is `radius-server`.  Since I'm not too familiar with 
`awk` I would appreciate it if someone could help me  **delete this line in place** , that would mean that I want the files to be modified and saved after the deletion is done. 
An example scenario is below -
`file 1` which is unmodified

```
 radius-server dz7HQQH4EqT5 1645-1646
 !
 oj5icqh1dGpSK
 !  
 alias exec t telnet
 alias exec sis show interface status
 !
```

`file 2`, after modification is -

```
radius-server dz7HQQH4EqT5 1645-1646
!
!
alias exec t telnet
alias exec sis show interface status
!
```

I understand that I can do a pattern matching method using `sed -i '/pattern/d'` to remove it but that is not what I want as the values change from file to file. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please be aware that "in place" isn't. The tool writes to a temporary file and replaces the original on successful completion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sed seems like the right tool:

```
sed -i '/radius-server/!b;n;n;d' filename
```

How it works:

```
/radius-server/!b # as long as it's NOT 'radius-server' do nothing (branch to end)
n # read next line (replace current line with next line)
n # same as above - we now read 2 lines
d # delete the current line
```

UPDATE - to modify multiple files, simply use glob instead of filename, e.g.

```
sed -i '/radius-server/!b;n;n;d' *
```

Comment: @don_crissti true, but then the awk solution doesn't work either, nor does the OP's awk matcher. arzyfex's solution fails because all pattern lines remain, whereas the OP clearly asked for n+2 to be deleted.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot for the help. :)

Comment: @don_crissti Add a good solution, and I'll delete mine.

Comment: @don_crissti I think part of the issue is undefined behavior for consecutive patterns - suppose you have 3 consecutive lines, according to the rule you have to delete line #3, but what about  lines #4,#5 ? one interpretation would be to delete all 3 lines (last pattern +2 lines), but if last pattern is no more, does it still count for purpose of deleting #5? Are you supposed to delete a target if in same pass you deleted source for choosing the target?

Comment: @Dani_l How can you say that "arzyfex's solution fails because all pattern lines remain",  As OP has already said, it worked for him/her.

Comment: @arzyfex - yours will fail too (see my first comment here). Basically, your `awk` - just like the `sed` here - will fail if there are multiple lines matching that aren't at least _N+1_ lines away from each other. However, since the question here is _definitely_ about files with a single occurrence of pattern (OP says _"delete this line"_ - so it's just one line), both answers here work. And let's just leave it like that. I'll ask a different question later on where I'll specify that pattern may occur on multiple, random lines (so a more general case as opposed to this particular case).

Comment: @don_crissti - thanks  how to achieve this using gnu awk ? could you please update on my answer ?

Answer (score 1):

**Unless you have GNU awk 4.1.0 or later...**

You won't have such an option as sed's `-i` option so instead do:

```
for file in *
do
awk -v lines=2 'BEGIN { ignore = -1 } /radius-server/ { ignore = NR + lines } NR != ignore { print }' "$file"
done > result.txt
```

This works as follows:

```
BEGIN { ignore = -1 }             # initialize ignore with -1 so NR will never
                                  # be equal to it by accident

/radius-server/ { ignore = NR + lines } # when the radius-server is found, set ignore to the
                                  # line we want to ignore

NR != ignore { print }            # unless the current line is that line, print
                                  # it.
```

Note: the `-i` is not magic, it is also creating a temporary file `sed` just handles it for you.

**Update**

If you need to recurse into subdirectories:

```
find . -type f -exec awk ... {} ; > result.txt
```

In both cases, you should probably put result.txt in a different directory. Otherwise, it will be matched and used as an input file.

Comment: Thanks, this does solve most  of my problem. The only thing that has not been addressed is modifying it in place. Is there any way of editing the file and saving it? I don't want to create a temp file. I just want the original file(s) to be modified. Also, there are multiple files in the folder so that should be kept in mind. Much appreciated!

Comment: @Zzrot - are you on a `gnu` setup ? If not,  your tools might not support editing in place.

Comment: @Zzrot : As don_crissti said, you won't be able to edit in place. but there is workaround for that. please refer my updated answer.

Comment: @arzyfex Thanks but it still doesnt fully work for me. Essentially what i'm trying is to replace `filename` with `*` . where `*` reads all the files in the folder. So I don't think the edited version works still. Thanks for getting back so promptly.

Comment: @Zzrot - please add your awk flavor & version to your post.

Comment: @Zzrot : Try updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
PATH_TO_FOLDER="/some/path/to/folder/"
FILE_EXTENSION=".ext"
FILES=$(ls ${PATH_TO_FOLDER}/*${FILE_EXTENSION})

for FILE in $FILES; do
FILENAME=$(basename $FILE ${FILE_EXTENSION})
TMP_FILE=${PATH_TO_FOLDER}/${FILENAME}.tmp
awk -v Lines=2 '{if($0~"radius-server"){ 
print;
for(i=0;i<=Lines;i++)
{
getline;
if(i==Lines){
next;
}else{
print; 
}
} 
}
else{
print;
}
}' $FILE > $TMP_FILE
mv ${TMP_FILE} ${FILE}
```

In principle this should work. Basically if the line contains radius-server that line will be printed and then it will iterate over the next 3 lines 0 will print the first line 1 will print the second line and then 3 will skip the third line altogether. For all other cases the lines are printed as is.