# Delete Nth line from each line matching a pattern

Tags: text-processing

I have several files like `file1`, `file2` ... etc in the same directory and each file may contain several lines matching `PATTERN`.
I would like to delete the `N`th line from each line matching `PATTERN` e.g. with `N` = `3` and `file1` content like

```
1 no match
2 PATTERN
3 same PATTERN
4 no match here
5 no match here either
6 another PATTERN
7 again, no match
8 no
9 last line
```

the expected output is

```
1 no match
2 PATTERN
3 same PATTERN
4 no match here
7 again, no match
8 no
```

Editing the files in-place is a bonus, not a requirement (though there's at least one `gnu` tool that I know of that could edit them all in one go...)

---

<sub>A similar question was asked [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/280242) however that is a particular case (there's just a single line matching pattern in each file and the solutions there would only work with multiple lines matching pattern if they're separated by at least *N*+1 non-matching lines).</sub>

Comment: If a line matching the pattern is to be deleted because of a previous match,  should it still delete the following n-th, or not?

Comment: @guido - yes, it should always delete the Nth; I think the example is pretty clear.

Comment: @don_crissti, I agree your example is very clear.  It made me realize what you were really asking when my first attempt failed.  I think the easiest way around this issue is a double use of `tac`, as I suggest [in my answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/280689/135943).  Congrats on a question that's much trickier than it first appears.  :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `awk` for this I believe like so:

```
awk -vN=3 '/PATTERN/ {skips[FNR+N]=1;} {if(!(FNR in skips)) print;}' <file>
```

so each time we hit `PATTERN` we'll record the line that is `N` away from here, and only print those lines we have not marked for skipping.

with gawk you could use `-i inplace` as well to do it in place

As you noted, that wouldn't handle multiple files.  Of course, you could wrap with a `for` loop to iterate over all the files, but if there aren't enough to make the commandline too long you could also do it like so:

```
 awk -vN=3 '{if(FNR==1) split("", skips, ":");} /PATTERN/ {skips[FNR+N]=1;} {if(!(FNR in skips)) print;}' *
```

where we reset `skips` to an empty array each time `FNR` hits 1, so the start of each file.
With `gnu awk` you could write it as:

```
gawk -i inplace 'FNR==1{delete nr};/PATTERN/{nr[FNR+3]++};!(FNR in nr)' file*
```

Answer (score 2):

I like a 2-pass mechanism so we can use `sed -i`:

```
for file in file1 ...
do sed -i "$file" -e "$(awk <"$file" -v N=3 '/PATTERN/{ print (NR+N) "d" }')"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for f in file1 file2 file...; do
  sed -i -f <(grep -n PATTERN "$f" | while IFS=: read line rest; do printf "%dd; " $((line+3)); done) "$f"
done
```

To split that apart:

1. Loop over file1 file2 file...
2. build up a sed expression inside the process substitution, to eventually run against the file.
3. `grep` outputs line numbers matching PATTERN in the file (along with the actual matching line).

Sample output:

```
2:2 PATTERN
3:3 same PATTERN
6:6 another PATTERN
```

4. the while loop strips the line number off, discarding the matching line, then sending it to printf, incremented by 3
5. printf prints the targeted line number, followed by the sed `d` delete command and a separating semicolon.

Sample output (as input for `sed`):

```
5d; 6d; 9d;
```

This method allows for a good amount of flexibility; you could set `N=3` and use `$((line+N))` as the printf argument.

To account for the in-place edit, I assume a sed that supports `-i` "in-place" editing.

Answer (score 2):

This use case just *begs* for using `ex`.

Unfortunately, since deleting the third line *after* a given line may delete a line containing PATTERN and thus cause the deletion associated with that line to be skipped (or worse, to delete the incorrect line), you need to reverse the file using e.g. `tac` first.  Then you can delete the third line *before* each instance of PATTERN, and reverse the file once more:

```
for f in *.txt; do printf %s\\n '%!tac' 'g/PATTERN/-3d' '%!tac' x | ex "$f"; done
```

If you have `tac` available I think this is the cleanest solution.

---

**For a fully POSIX compliant solution**, making use of my answer to:

- [Reverse sequence of a file with POSIX tools?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/280685/135943)

You can do it like so:

```
for f in *.txt; do printf %s\\n '%!sed -n '\''1h;1\!{x;H;};${g;p;}'\' 'g/PATTERN/-3d' '%!sed -n '\''1h;1\!{x;H;};${g;p;}'\' x | ex "$f"; done
```

Not very readable, but functional.