# Reverse sequence of a file with POSIX tools?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, cat, posix

Is there any clean, clear-cut POSIX equivalent to `tac`?

Readability as well as succinctness should both be considered.

Comment: does it need to hold the original in memory (pipeline as input), or can we assume a seekable file?

Comment: @JeffSchaller, there could be two types of answers: one for processing in a pipeline, one for editing a file in place.  I'd like to know both.  Also, both should ideally work at least as well as `tac`.

Comment: FYI I just browsed [tac's source code](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=coreutils.git;a=blob;f=src/tac.c;h=4681f3ab9b0f2a8f574e683b9dc4d24657e76fb4;hb=HEAD) and I see that it writes stdin to a temp file, which it then tac's and then unlinks. In case that informs solutions here.

Comment: @don_crissti, I upvoted your answer there.  If it were an answer here I would accept it.  :)  (Maybe add the `ex` version to it first, and show its use in a pipeline.)

Comment: @don_crissti, my reply clarified: This question I'm commenting on is mine.  The answer you wrote is on another question that I didn't write.  If your answer had been posted in answer to this question, I would accept it.  (And I might add to it how to use `ex` to accomplish the same.)  If you don't want to post here, I will do so myself, borrowing from your answer elsewhere.  :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cleanest *POSIX* equivalent would be

```
tail -r
```

as

```
-r          Reverse. Copies lines from the specified starting point in
            the file in reverse order. The default for r is to print the
            entire file in reverse order.
```

[has been accepted for the next *POSIX* issue](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=877) (and hopefully, it will be soon supported on all platforms).

---

If `tail -r` is not available the "classic" text processing tools can be successfully used - as you and others have shown - to reverse the lines in a file.
Readability and conciseness aside, even old `ed` can do it:

```
ed -s infile <<\IN
g/^/m0
,p
q
IN
```

or, if it's the output from a pipeline that you want to reverse - read it into the text buffer first:

```
ed -s <<\IN
r ! your | pipeline | goes | here
g/^/m0
,p
q
IN
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with a `sed` one-liner as follows, though it is certainly not readable for the "uninitiated":

```
sed -n '1h;1!{x;H;};${g;p;}' file.txt
```

---

**Explanation:**

`-n` suppresses `sed`'s default action of printing each line.

`1h` causes the first line to be stored in the hold space.

`1!{...}` applies this block of commands to all lines *except* for the first one.

`x` swaps the hold space and the pattern space.  (The pattern space is where each line is stored while it is being processed.)  Then `H` appends to the hold space a newline followed by the (new) contents of the pattern space.

The final block `${...}` is only applied when the last line is reached.  `g` gets the contents of the hold space and puts it in the pattern space, and `p` prints the pattern space.

Of course this depends on being able to hold the entire file in memory at once; it may fail on extremely large files.

Comment: you can simplify it as: `sed '1!x;H;1h;$!d;g' file`

Comment: Oh wow, that's actually kind of mind-blowing to me, since i'm only semi-initiated. I made it a shell function as in `tac(){sed '1!x;H;1h;$!d;g'}`

Answer (score 3):

Here's an awk script that stores the whole file in memory:

```
awk '{line[NR]=$0} END {for (i=NR; i>=1; i--) print line[i]}' file
```

Phrased as a shell function:

```
tac () { awk '{line[NR]=$0} END {for (i=NR; i>=1; i--) print line[i]}' "$@"; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a <strike>clean</strike> clear-cut POSIX solution for on-disk files:

```
#!/bin/sh
function tac () {
  lines=$(wc -l < "$1")
  while [ $lines -gt 0 ]
  do
    head -n $lines "$1" | tail -n 1
    lines=$((lines-1))
  done
}
```

The main down-side is that it reads the file once for every line in the file. [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/head.html) doesn't specify an upper limit for `-n` *number*, so large files might overrun an implementation's choice. POSIX does limit [arithmetic expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_04) to signed long integer, though (circa 2,147,483,647).

A similar construct could be made from `tail -n -$lines input | head -n 1`.

Given the requirement to read the file so many times, these are likely less performant than `tac`.

Comment: My implementation of `wc` includes the filename in the output, so `[ $lines -gt 0 ]` will break, won't it?  (I thought the filename in the output was standard.)

Comment: That's why I was careful to do `wc < file` instead of `wc file`

Comment: :) I just red the chat transcript and saw your message... Apparently my 1st question + the associated badge didn't spur any excitement (in chat, that is). Thanks anyway ! On another note: yet another portable way to do this is to split the file one-line-per-piece and cat the pieces in reverse order.

Comment: I looked, and just learned that the [split](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/split.html) utility has a *specified* maximum of 676 files, so the splitting would have to be done by hand. GNU split's doc indicates it supports "an arbitrary number of output files".

Comment: Not really by hand as you can get the total number of lines, calculate to split into 676 pieces that you then split into one line pieces etc... It's not a complicated algorithm. I tend to ignore posix limitations as most times they are really hilarious...

Comment: "signed long integer, though (circa 2,147,483,647)" AFAIUI, you could get the exact size (in bits) of a `long` with `getconf LONG_BIT`. https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2008edition/basedefs/limits.h.html

Answer (score 1):

**[POSIX vi](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/vi.html)** has you covered, as does **[ed](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ed.html)** or **[ex](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html)**.

I prefer **vi** myself if I am going to be looking at the output anyway.

Command Mode, of course:

```
:g/^/m0
```

You can always give :g a range if you don't want to reverse the whole file, as long as you pay attention to where and how you are moving things:

```
:1,10g/^/m0
```

You can script it with `ed` or `ex` using something like this:

```
$ ed -s infile <<IN
g/^/m0
,p
w
IN
```

vs

```
$ ex -s infile <<EOS
g/^/move0
wq
EOS
```

I do it all the time.

The "-r" switch to [tail](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tail.html) is not POSIX-compliant at the time of this post:

```
tail [-f] [-c number|-n number] [file]
```