# Copy & paste cleanly into a command like grep, without terminal echo cluttering the output?

Tags: shell, grep, clipboard

I have some test output, looking like

```
PASS: tests/test_mutex_rmw
PASS: tests/test_mutex_trylock
PASS: tests/test_malloc_irreg
FAIL: tests/ARMCI_PutS_latency
FAIL: tests/ARMCI_AccS_latency
PASS: tests/test_groups
PASS: tests/test_group_split
PASS: tests/test_malloc_group
FAIL: tests/test_accs
FAIL: tests/test_accs_dla
```

I want to filter the output to just view the failures. It would be convenient to just copy the text from screen and paste into stdin to pass into grep, e.g.

```
grep FAIL
```

and Shift-Ctrl-V (or middle mouse button) to copy the text in.

What I want to see is just

```
FAIL: tests/ARMCI_PutS_latency
FAIL: tests/ARMCI_AccS_latency
FAIL: tests/test_accs
FAIL: tests/test_accs_dla
```

But instead, the input pasted in is displayed to screen, and because of buffering the input gets mixed with the final output:

```
$ grep FAIL
PASS: tests/test_mutex_rmw
PASS: tests/test_mutex_trylock
PASS: tests/test_malloc_irreg
FAIL: tests/ARMCI_PutS_latency
FAIL: tests/ARMCI_AccS_latency
PASS: tests/test_groups
PASS: tests/test_group_split
PASS: tests/test_malloc_group
FAIL: teFAIL: tests/ARMCI_PutS_latency
sts/test_accs
FAIL: tests/test_accs_dla
FAIL: tests/ARMCI_AccS_latency
FAIL: tests/test_accs
FAIL: tests/test_accs_dla
```

It would make sense to me for the input to first be provided to cat and then passed to grep, `cat | grep FAIL`, but that doesn't actually help. The buffer mixup still occurs.

Of course it can be filtered cleanly if the data is placed in a file which is passed to grep. But what I'm looking for is a convenience tool to simply provide light filtering of text copied from the terminal output via the clipboard buffer. How is that best done?

Equivalently, how can pasting be done without echoing to screen (providing data silently as stdin for the command)?

One method is to explicitly switch off echoing,

```
stty -echo; grep FAIL; stty echo
```

That does work, but I suspect there are ways of doing it without toggling stty.  Do you know other shell-based approaches?

I use bash (on Debian GNU/Linux), but POSIX shell solutions are also interesting.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and tell us what operating system you are using.

Comment: bash on Linux, added to question. POSIX shell is also interesting.

Comment: Is there some reason you can't pipe the output to grep when you execute the command that generates it?  command | grep FAIL

Comment: Several reasons.  For one thing, I want all the output in general, that is I'll want to inspect other parts of the log in detail. Besides that, the full output actually is being written to file (via tee).  Not convenient to inject the grep at the point where the log is actually generated.  The question here is just for making it easier to quickly monitor progress and check parts of the log while the process is still running. Sometimes you're not expecting failure anyway, and want to filter what was supposed to be a routine output that you wouldn't have expected to need to inspect closely.

Answer (score 23):

Mark the text with your mouse, then use `xclip`:

```bsh
xclip -o | grep FAIL
```

or copied from Clipboard (Ctrl-c):

```bsh
xclip -selection clipboard -o | grep FAIL
```

Or:

```bsh
xclip -sel c -o | grep FAIL
```

for short.

Comment: Nice variant. I didn't have xclip installed, so it's a new tool for me. I'm hoping to find methods that react to Copy to give more control of the data transfer (the `-selection clipboard` option here "steals" anything that happens to be in the clipboard). I'll try playing with the other xclip options.

Comment: `xsel` is a very similar program you might look into a well

Comment: (For the record, macOS — which is also Unix — has equivalent commands `pbcopy` and `pbpaste`.)

Answer (score 17):

If you are using `bash` or any other Bourne-like shell, you can use a [`here-document`](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html).  Begin your command with `grep FAIL << 'EOF'` and press Enter.  Bash will prompt with a `>` symbol to show that more command input is expected from the terminal.  Then paste in your input, and enter `EOF` by itself on a line.  The output from `grep` will appear after the `EOF` line.

```
$ grep FAIL << 'EOF'
> PASS: tests/test_mutex_rmw
PASS: tests/test_mutex_trylock
PASS: tests/test_malloc_irreg
FAIL: tests/ARMCI_PutS_latency
FAIL: tests/ARMCI_AccS_latency
PASS: tests/test_groups
PASS: tests/test_group_split
PASS: tests/test_malloc_group
FAIL: tests/test_accs
FAIL: tests/test_accs_dla
EOF
FAIL: tests/ARMCI_PutS_latency
FAIL: tests/ARMCI_AccS_latency
FAIL: tests/test_accs
FAIL: tests/test_accs_dla
```

Make sure you quote the `EOF` (or any part of it), with any quoting operator, to make sure no parameter expansion, command substitution or arithmetic expansion is performed inside the here-document and `\` characters be not mangled.

To minimise key strokes, you could make it:

```
grep FAIL<<\.
<paste-text-here>
.
```

Comment: Needs a few more keystrokes than the sponge method, but otherwise a useful alternative method, thanks.

Answer (score 16):

You can use `sponge` to soak up all the *stdin* before writing it to *stdout*. (On Debian it's in the package `moreutils`.)

```
grep FAIL | sponge
```

or

```
sponge | grep FAIL
```

If you don't have `sponge` you can implement a simple approximation to it with POSIX code like this

```
#!/bin/sh
[ -n "$1" ] && exec 1>"$1"
umask 077
tmp="${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/${0##*/}.$$.tmp"
cat >"$tmp"
cat "$tmp"
rm -f "$tmp"
```

You mentioned you would really like `sponge` to have "*an option to not echo the stdin*" it doesn't echo *stdin*. What you're seeing is a function of the terminal driver being left at its default of echoing typed text. I'd be inclined to use a function such as this

```
esponge() {
    local g ss
    if [ -t 0 ]
    then
        g=$(stty -g)
        stty -echoe
    fi
    sponge "$@"
    ss=$?
    [ -n "$g" ] && stty "$g"
    return $ss
}

esponge | grep FAIL
```

Yet another alternative but equivalent to `sponge` is to send the input through `tac` (not POSIX but may be installed on some systems that don't have `sponge`)

```
tac | tac | grep FAIL
```

Or replace each instance of `tac` with one of [these POSIX alternatives](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/280685/100397)

Comment: Excellent. sponge is pretty much exactly what I had in mind. Behaves like cat but separates stdin from stdout. The only way to perfect it further would be with an option to not echo the stdin, but I guess stty is needed to do that (or xclip with careful timing of clipboard contents)

Comment: Testing the sponge method some more, the pasted input can easily be visually separated from the filtered output simply by tapping `enter` a couple of times after pasting to get a gap of a few lines.  Less need to avoid echoing the input in that case.

Comment: Note that `sponge` used to be a 5 line `perl` script before it was rewriten in C. That particular `sponge` usage can be written just `perl -0777 -pe ''`

Comment: The advantage of something like this over `xclip`/`xsel` is that it can be used when the shell is on a remote system, e.g. via ssh/docker/qemu. Implementation can also be simpler for practical text-based cases, like `sed ':b;N;bb'` or `printf '%s\n' "$(cat)"`.

Comment: Another quick-and-dirty way of simulating `sponge` (if you don't have the official version) is `cat -n | sort -n | sed 's/ *[0-9]* //'`

Answer (score 8):

While I'd go for [the `xclip`/`xsel` approach](/a/693721) that is by far the safest where applicable, in `zsh`, to make sure that whilst you paste text into `grep`, the terminal is not echoing back what you type, so that only the output of `grep` be seen, you can do:

```
STTY=-echo grep FAIL
```

and then paste your input, terminated with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> (twice if the input doesn't end in a newline character).

From [the manual](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#index-STTY):

> `STTY`
> If this parameter is set in a command's environment, the shell runs
> the stty command with the value of this parameter as arguments in
> order to set up the terminal before executing the command.  The
> modes apply only to the command, and are reset when it finishes or
> is suspended.  If the command is suspended and continued later with
> the fg or wait builtins it will see the modes specified by STTY, as
> if it were not suspended.  This (intentionally) does not apply if
> the command is continued via 'kill -CONT'.  STTY is ignored if the
> command is run in the background, or if it is in the environment of
> the shell but not explicitly assigned to in the input line.  This
> avoids running stty at every external command by accidentally
> exporting it.  Also note that STTY should not be used for window
> size specifications; these will not be local to the command.

You can achieve something similar in other POSIX-like shells (though here without handling suspensions) by defining a helper function such as:

```
noecho() (
  saved_tty_settings=$(stty -g)
  trap 'stty "$saved_tty_settings"' INT QUIT EXIT
  stty -echo
  "$@"
)
```

And then enter:

```
noecho grep FAIL
```

More generally, [pasting text into a terminal is potentially dangerous](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/39118) even if you don't paste it as input to a shell. Here, if the text to be pasted has been copied from a terminal emulator in the first place, the risk is more limited though as terminal emulators won't store things like `^C` / `^Z` / `^D` control characters in clipboard selections.

Comment: Controlling echo via an environment variable is a convenient method. Thanks.

Comment: I think POSIX-ly `$saved_tty_settings` should *not* be double-quoted. [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/stty.html) allows `stty -g` to print "an unspecified form that can be used as arguments" (plural!); then it says "the form used shall not contain any characters that would require quoting to avoid word expansion by the shell". IMO this indicates that some implementations may require word splitting from unquoted `$saved_tty_settings` (i.e. they will fail when double-quoted) and no implementation shall require `$saved_tty_settings` to be double-quoted.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski, that was [a defect in the POSIX specification](https://www.austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=1532) that will be fixed in the next release (on my request). No `stty` implementation has ever required the output of `stty -g` be split+glob'bed for reinput, that would not make sense.

Comment: Good to know, thank you. I can see you're involved in improving these things. Kudos.

Answer (score 3):

What's wrong with simply piping your pasted text through echo? At least for simple text like yours that works well enough. The only thing to remember is to quote the lines. So you write `echo "` , paste your text, close the quote and pipe it as desired. (This assumes, like in your example, that `echo`does not corrupt your text. Control chars etc. may cause trouble with echo.)

```
$ echo "PASS: tests/test_mutex_trylock
PASS: tests/test_malloc_irreg
FAIL: tests/ARMCI_PutS_latency
FAIL: tests/ARMCI_AccS_latency
PASS: tests/test_mutex_trylock
PASS: tests/test_malloc_irreg
FAIL: tests/ARMCI_PutS_latency
FAIL: tests/ARMCI_AccS_latency
PASS: tests/test_groups
PASS: tests/test_group_split
PASS: tests/test_malloc_group
FAIL: tests/test_accs
"| grep FAIL
FAIL: tests/ARMCI_PutS_latency
FAIL: tests/ARMCI_AccS_latency
FAIL: tests/ARMCI_PutS_latency
FAIL: tests/ARMCI_AccS_latency
FAIL: tests/test_accs
```

Input and output are clearly separated. This method uses only the simplest *nix commands and is easier to remember for me than the syntax of a here document.

If you want to use the text as commands you can use echo as command substitution, for texts that are not too long.

I didn't know xclip, and msys2 doesn't seem to have it, so I'll continue to use my stupid [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) method. I simply echo the buffer contents and make that the desired command's command line parameters.

Because **the text** consists of multiple line the pasted stuff (but not the echo, or the entire substitution!) it **must be quoted.**

Because **the command substitution is not quoted** the shell parses the echo output back into separate words.

The example below would of course be better solved with `find ... -print0` (among others, file names with spaces don't work here) but it illustrates the point. (And anybody who puts spaces in paths deserves to be served a restraining order for computers anyway. Yes, Bill, I'm talking to you.)

```
$ ls -1 a*
a1
a2
a3
a4
a5
aa
$ ls -l $(echo "a1
a2
a3
a4
a5
aa
")
-rw-r--r-- 1 Peter None 0 Mar 11 11:59 a1
-rw-r--r-- 1 Peter None 0 Mar 11 11:59 a2
-rw-r--r-- 1 Peter None 0 Mar 11 11:59 a3
-rw-r--r-- 1 Peter None 0 Mar 11 11:59 a4
-rw-r--r-- 1 Peter None 0 Mar 11 11:59 a5
-rw-r--r-- 1 Peter None 0 Mar 11 11:58 aa
```

Comment: "_anybody who puts spaces in paths deserves to be served a restraining order_" There are three sorts of code, (1) throwaway code for specific instances where spaces may or may not break it, but you know and understand the input is safe, (2) code that will break if given unexpected spaces, (3) code that is sufficiently carefully written to cope with spaces even if they are not expected. Aim to write for (1) or (3)

Comment: @roima Spaces by no means break the OP's use case, as demonstrated. They may break *file operations* that I used as an example below (to illustrate an add-on that was not the original question)  but do not, in the general case, break that method either. (And as you may know it is very hard to impossible to write shell code that is robust against pathological file names, so *everything* is <100%.)

Comment: As to the OP's requirements: I understood that the OP wants to avoid the terminal input mingling indistinguishably with the output (as is the case if you use the paste buffer simply as the terminal input, as in the OP's example). Using the text as explicit input (as with echo or a here document) seemed OK though, that is: The OP is not against echoing in general. This assumption is supported by the use case of parsing ASCII text (which echo handles just fine).

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I had not used your suggestion in the way that you now demonstrate, and for me it had broken. Your example now clearly shows that it works +1

Comment: Quoting via echo does work well enough.  Has the obvious problem if there happens to be quotation characters in the text, but in many instances that won't be a problem.

Comment: One major drawback to doing nothing special is that sometimes the content being pasted is very large, which (on in many terminal emulators) means the user must wait for a long time as the pasted content is written to and echoed by the terminal. Obviously a situation to be avoided, but sometimes that's the hand you're dealt. In such cases, having `sponge` or messing with STTY is a very welcome backup plan.

Comment: MSYS2 not supporting `xclip` is unsurprising once you consider what the `x` in `xclip` originally stood for. (Though I think it's been upgraded to support the Wayland clipboard as well, at this point.)

Answer (score 3):

For anyone using MSYS2, you can utilize `/dev/clipboard`:

```
grep FAIL /dev/clipboard
```

Answer (score 2):

Another `moreutils` solution with the advantage (or caveat, depending on your perspective) that it's a little more interactive, you can use `vipe` in a pipeline:

```bsh
echo "" | vipe | grep FAIL
```

Your `$EDITOR` will launch, you can paste the text into it, even massage it however you see fit, and then save and close the editor. `grep` will  be run on the final contents, without the input being shown in the terminal.