# Delete lines x after a match

Tags: sed

How can I use `sed` to delete lines two (or any number) after a match but not including the match and lines in between?

For example:

```
Enter command below
> login
Command valid
Enter your password at the below prompt
Remember to make sure no-one is looking at your screen
> mysecretword
Password accepted
```

I want to only delete the line "> mysecretword" on account of it being two lines after the line "Enter your password at the below prompt". I can't use absolute line number positions, because the match could appear any number of lines after the start of the file.

Searching online I find a lot of solutions like `sed '/Enter your password.*/,+3d' filex`, but this would also remove the "Enter your password..." line and the following line, which is not what I want. I only want to remove one line, which is a certain number of lines after a match.

How can I do this with `sed` (or indeed any other commonly-available tool)?

Comment: Did you try using a single line instead of a range?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams not sure what you mean, if you are asking if I can use an absolute position this is not possible as the file can have any number of lines before the match (updated my question to clarify this)

Comment: See [Delete Nth line from each line matching a pattern](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/280641/22142) for the more general case....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps

```
sed '/^Enter your password/ {
n
n
d
}' file
```

or equivalently:

```
$ sed '/^Enter your password/ {n;n;d;}' file
Enter command below
> login
Command valid
Enter your password at the below prompt
Remember to make sure no-one is looking at your screen
Password accepted
```

Answer (score 2):

For generic cases, see this excellent answer from Ed Morton: [Printing with sed or awk a line following a matching pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17908555/printing-with-sed-or-awk-a-line-following-a-matching-pattern)
.

> d) Print every record except the Nth record after some regexp:
>
> ```
> awk 'c&&!--c{next}/regexp/{c=N}1' file
> ```

Applying for given input

```bsh
$ awk 'c && !--c{next} /^Enter your password/{c=2} 1' ip.txt 
Enter command below
> login
Command valid
Enter your password at the below prompt
Remember to make sure no-one is looking at your screen
Password accepted
```

- `/^Enter your password/{c=2} 1` here `c` is nth line after the match to be ignored, `1` to print input record
- `c && !--c{next}` the `&&` is short circuit operator, so as long as `c` evaluates to false, `c` won't be decremented. After `c` is set to a value, it will be decremented as long as it doesn't reach `0`

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '/Enter your password.*/{N;p;N;d;}' file
```